# Recognizing when road is uphill and when downhill using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, road, network-analysis

How do I automatically recognize and cut roads of a great network in places when the roads are changing the path uphill and downhill using QGIS?

I have a geotiff dem.

[image]

[image]

Schematic truck's transport

[image]

Comment: I cannot read your contour map well, so I am probably wrong about your `up` and `down` definitions... Just thought you might want to calculate (if QGIS) `z(end_point($geometry)) - z(start_point($geometry))` and see if it returns positive or negative value.

Comment: Up or down depends on what direction you are traveling. How to tell?

Comment: @BERA: You are right, that could be a problem (Up or down depends on what direction you are traveling). I analyze truck traffic. It is important when a truck drives a load uphill or downhill, fuel consumption is different.

Comment: Do you want to split existing linestrings wherever the direction changes? Or always use the existing features as is?

Comment: The way cartographers usually symbolize this is by using arrows or chevrons that point uphill, rather than labeling each segment of road as "up" or "down". But of course, that isn't your question…

Comment: I added a picture to show what is the issue. I see that these terms are unclear to you. I'll try to clarify it again. Fuel consumption varies depending on the climb or fall of the road. I need to calculate the average slope for each of these segments of the road. (average slope is not a problem I can solve it). The problem is:
1. How to recognize the direction from where the goods come out,
2. and how to split segments depending on the climb or fall of the road?

sorry for my English

Comment: @ndawson: As a first step, the line should be divided. Then somehow give a minus or plus sign for each change.

Comment: @Nathan: It's not a problem with labeling or map design, it's a classic calculation

Comment: @ Kazuhito: I dont know ho to use your formula. What is the input?

Comment: @nagib Exactly—this is why I say "but that's not your question". :-)

Comment: @nagib The input 3D geometry (`$geometry`) can be given (e.g.) by GRASS `v.drape`.